# Connecting 2 laptops with docking stations to a split screen set-up

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

I work for 2 companies that require use of a docking station.  I need dual monitor set-up for both docking stations.  Is there a way to share a dual monitor set-up between the 2 docking stations?  1 is for a Dell and the other is HP.  I am not sure what I would use to connect.  A picture of the connecting part would be helpful as I am really only familiar with USB and HDMI ports.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If both Your docks have dual digital video outputs ([HDMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI), [DVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) or [DisplayPort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort)) then You need an expensive **4x2 HDMI switch** like <s>[Atlona AT-HD4-V42](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005CKWRVI)</s><sup>1</sup> or [Octava 4x2 HDMI Matrix Switch](http://www.octavainc.com/HDMI%20matrix%20switch%204x2%20port.html)

If docks have only one video output interface, then in addition to 4x2 switch You'll need an again expensive solution to extend that that single output signal into two, like [Matrox DualHead2Go Digital SE](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital_se/) **multi-display adapter** or **external video adapter** like [Aluratek USB to HDMI 1080p Adapter](http://aluratek.com/usb-to-hdmi-1080p-adapter-with-audio) for each docks that is missing an interface.

On the other hand, You might use a not too expensive DisplayPort switch like [SIIG CE-KV0411-S1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007ZT1GQ6) and use mentioned [Matrox DualHead2Go Digital SE](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital_se/) adapter to split its output to Your screens, but this seems to be not possible with HDMI or DVI.

Please update Your question with exact docks and monitors models for further details.

<sup>1</sup> According to manufacturer [Atlona AT-HD4-V42](http://atlona.com/product/at-hd4-v42/) is only 4x1 switch and does not meet the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You need a dual video two port KVM switch.  Examples:
https://www.startech.com/en-us/server-management/kvm-switches?page=1&sort=relevance&filter_kvmports=2&filter_kvmdual=2

If by chance the link fails in the future a search for "2 port dual display KVM switch" or similar wording on your preferred search engine should provide examples.  Replacing the word "display" with "HDMI" or whatever video port is in use may narrow it down but may narrow it down too much, which gets to my next point.

You mention HDMI for video and my examples are DVI and DisplayPort, not to worry as HDMI is backward compatible with both.  Use of inexpensive passive adapter cables should be all you need to have HDMI computers and monitors with a DVI or DP KVM switch.  Finding KVM switch with HDMI may be preferred to remove any doubt.  I use StarTech as examples as I am familiar with them, don't consider this an endorsement as I have not used anything but StarTech KVM switches in some time so I do not know how they compare, only that they seem to work well.

The docks don't play much into this, it's a matter of plugging two computers into the same two displays, keyboard, and mouse.  Treat the docks as the computers being hooked up and the laptops connect to the dock normally.  The connection setup and process will vary slightly based on the VKM switch and docks.  Documentation for the KVM switch setup will come with the KVM switch, it's common to be able to review this documentation online before you buy if this concerns you.  Most KVM switches assume both computers will have the same connections, such as 2 HDMI and a single USB.  If that is not the case then consider means to reach this similarity with adapters or seek a KVM switch that allows dissimilar connections to each computer.

One means to reduce desktop clutter is to seek a dock with a built in KVM, or a display with a built in KVM.  Use of dual displays complicate this and limit options.  With the reduced clutter will be more expensive hardware and more complex install, depending on your budget and skill a more conventional setup may be in order.

I realize this question is old but answered regardless as this sounds like something that can still be a useful answer for someone.